# MediaRecorder changes size without provocation

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas, webrtc, mediarecorder-api

I'm using the [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) API along with the [Canvas captureStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream) method to encode a VP8 video stream of a canvas in browser.  This data is sent to FFmpeg via binary web socket.

```
var outputCaptureStream = $('canvas')[0].captureStream(30);
var mediaRecoder = new MediaRecoder(outputCaptureStream, {
  mimeType: 'video/webm'
});

mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
  ffmpegStdin.write(e.data);
}

mediaRecoder.start(1000);
```

For some reason, the stream seems to be randomly switching to a lower resolution mid-stream.  FFmpeg isn't happy about this:

> Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:1280x720 fmt:yuv420p to size:1024x576 fmt:yuv420p
>
> [vp8 @ 0x2a02c00] Upscaling is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
> [vp8 @ 0x2a02c00] If you want to help, upload a sample of this file to ftp://upload.ffmpeg.org/incoming/ and contact the ffmpeg-devel mailing list. (ffmpeg-devel@ffmpeg.org)

I suspect that it has something to do with excessive CPU usage and that Firefox is trying to be helpful by scaling down the video.  My questions:

- Does Firefox scale down the video on the fly?
- If so, what conditions cause this to happen?  (CPU load?  Stream backpressure?)
- Is it possible to prevent Firefox from doing this?
- Is there a different explanation for this behavior that I'm missing?

Comment: is the canvas size fixed? are you streaming your camera stream into the canvas?

Comment: @mido Canvas size is completely fixed.  I'm drawing frames on requestAnimationFrame, capped at 30FPS via the "better refined approach" here:  http://codetheory.in/controlling-the-frame-rate-with-requestanimationframe/

Comment: can you share the code, I could give it a try and see if I can spot the issue..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox will rescale (downscale) WebRTC/getUserMedia video if it detects the system's CPU is being overloaded. There are a few prefs in about:config that control this behavior, but it's not controllable via JS.

You can disable the feature by setting

media.navigator.load_adapt=false

You can look at the other media.navigator.load_adapt.* flags for some control over the behavior. By default you will get downscaling if the CPU gets pegged more than 90% for 3 seconds.

Comment: After further testing, I found that `media.navigator.load_adapt=false` has no bearing on whether or not the output video is dynamically scaled mid-stream.  After more discussion in the IRC room, it was suggested that I open this bug report:  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1250345